# How to monitor 2of3 Coinbase Vault wallet using xpub

Tags: coinbase.com, multi-signature

I created a 2of3 wallet on Coinbase. I have 3 different xpub. I tried all 3 xpub on goochain.net but in all appear 0 balance. But I have 2 btc. How to monitor the 2of3 of Coinbase using xpub?

Comment: This is not the answer you are looking for. There is not an easy way to show multisig addresses (3CpowZDX3FJbfc9Q16FHeT98fp91T6Unu5) with xpub. Blockchain.info is only showing ordinary bitcoin addresses, like this: https://blockchain.info/xpub/xpub6BiVtCpG9fQPxnPmHXG8PhtzQdWC2Su4qWu6XW9tpWFYhxydCLJGrWBJZ5H6qTAHdPQ7pQhtpjiYZVZARo14qHiay2fvrX996oEP42u8wZy